# Vega lite use one data field for the axis and another for the label

Tags: svg, charts, axis-labels, vega, vega-lite

In [Vega Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/), is it possible to use one field of the data values as the axis value, and another field as the label?

If this is my vega lite spec, then the graph works correctly, but shows the dates on the x-axis.  How can I show the day names on the x-axis instead?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "description": "basic line graph",
  "data": {
    "values": [
        {"date":"2017-08-15", "dayName":"Tue","item":"foo","count":"0"},
        {"date":"2017-08-16", "dayName":"Wed","item":"foo","count":"11"},
        {"date":"2017-08-17", "dayName":"Thu","item":"foo","count":"7"},
        {"date":"2017-08-18", "dayName":"Fri","item":"foo","count":"28"},
        {"date":"2017-08-19", "dayName":"Sat","item":"foo","count":"0"},
        {"date":"2017-08-20", "dayName":"Sun","item":"foo","count":"0"},
        {"date":"2017-08-21", "dayName":"Mon","item":"foo","count":"0"}
    ]},
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "interpolate": "monotone"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

It shows the date field, `August 16`, `August 17` on the x-axis.  How can I make it show the dayName field instead?  It should show `Tue`, `Wed`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timeUnit`.

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "description": "basic line graph",
  "data": {
    "values": [
        {"date":"2017-08-15", "dayName":"Tue","item":"foo","count":"0"},
        {"date":"2017-08-16", "dayName":"Wed","item":"foo","count":"11"},
        {"date":"2017-08-17", "dayName":"Thu","item":"foo","count":"7"},
        {"date":"2017-08-18", "dayName":"Fri","item":"foo","count":"28"},
        {"date":"2017-08-19", "dayName":"Sat","item":"foo","count":"0"},
        {"date":"2017-08-20", "dayName":"Sun","item":"foo","count":"0"},
        {"date":"2017-08-21", "dayName":"Mon","item":"foo","count":"0"}
    ]},
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "interpolate": "monotone"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "timeUnit": "day",
      "field": "date", 
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

If you want to customize the label format, you can add [axis format](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#labels), as well

Comment: But I don't want to group the count values by dayName, I want to keep the layout by the date, but label the dates by their corresponding dayName. It's different semantics to what you suggested.